# Troubleshooting: Cannot get userId with Vuex in Vue 3 and Composition API

Tags: vuejs3, vuex, vue-composition-api

I'm learning about vuex, vue 3 and composition api and I'm trying to get a userId with vuex but I can't do it. I don't have mistakes in my code but it doesn't work too.

My main.js:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'bootstrap';
import {createStore} from 'vuex'
import vuex from 'vuex'


export default createStore({
    state:{
        Id: 'User'
    },
    mutations:{
        setId(state, id){
            state.Id = id;
        }
    },
    actions:{

    }
})
createApp(App).use(router).use(vuex).mount('#app')
```

My app.vue:

```
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue'
//import { useStore } from 'vuex'
import store from './store/store'

import HomeView from '../src/views/HomeView.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    HomeView
  },

  setup(){
    
    //const store = useStore();
    const user = ref({
      userId: localStorage.getItem('Id'),
    });
 
    console.log("adsdad")
    //Doesn't enter here, in OnMounted()
  onMounted(()=>{
    if(user.value.userId){  
      //store.state.Id('setId', user.value.userId);
      store.commit('setId', user.value.userId);
      console.log('ID asignado:', store.state.Id);
      
  }
  })
  //put validations
  }
}
</script>
```

I made a store.js, I've tried debugg also I asked chatGpt and nothing...

Answer (score 1):

> I don't have mistakes in my code but it doesn't work too.

First of all, you have BIG mistakes.

Second of all, if you're just starting out with Vue 3 and Composition API you should be using the official state management library [Pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/).  The [Vuex homepage](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) even mentions this right at the very top.

But assuming you have a *very* good reason to use Vuex, I will offer advice on what you've done wrong. I'll also assume you're using Vuex 4, which is the only version compatible with Vue 3.

In your main.js you don't `import vuex from 'vuex'` with Vuex 4.  You import `createStore` (which you've also done) and define your store, but if you define it directly in main.js **you don't export it**.  You assign it to a variable and provide it to the createApp `use()` function.

If you choose to define the store in a separate file, that's when you export it, then import it into main.js and again put it in the `use()` function.  It's all perfectly described in the [documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/#the-simplest-store)

When it comes to using the store in your components you're supposed to import the store with `import { useStore } from 'vuex'`.  This is also very clearly described in the [documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api.html).

Have I mentioned you should read the [documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) yet? It's very good!  Although circling back to the beginning of my post, scrap all that and **USE PINIA**